# ggplot2 label font bolding not working correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a box-plot with a subgroup highlighted.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(hrbrthemes)

mpg1 <- mpg %>% 
  mutate( type=ifelse(class=="subcompact","Highlighted","Normal"))
  
mpg1 %>%
  ggplot( aes(x=class, y=hwy, fill=type, alpha=type)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#69b3a2", "grey")) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values=c(1,0.1)) +
  theme_ipsum() +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.text = element_text(face = "bold")) +
  xlab("")
```

But as you can see in the image here, some x-axis labels are not bold correctly. I think it only happens with the letter "e".

[image: letter e not getting bolded.]

Comment: Try re starting `R` in a fresh session your code works fine!

Comment: I tried restarting RStudio but it's still happening...

Answer (score 0):

You reproducible snippet works as expected. Close all instances of R/RStudio and try again. Perhaps an R session is open in a terminal/command prompt? Or alternatively execute `dev.off()` until you hit `Error in dev.off() : cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)` message. Then create your plot again.

Comment: I made sure all R instances were terminated and also did dev.off() until I got "Error in dev.off() : cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)". It was still the same. I think there is something wrong with my Arial Narrow Bold ttf file. When I changed to theme_ipsum(base_family = "Arial"), it worked correctly.